# Modifying all DOM elements using Javascript

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am working on a page which has certain number of Dojo textarea elements.

```
                <textarea readonly class="readTextBox versionText"></textarea>
```

The number of these elements is more than one. I am trying to add a javascript function or formatting of a textarea. The function gives me certain line count for the textarea elements. The script is :

```
 <script type="application/javascript">
    window.onload=function() {
        var versionElement = document.getElementsByClassName("versionText");
        console.log("length:" + versionElement.length);
        var versionElementText = versionElement.value;

        var lines = versionElementText.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/);
        var rowCount = 0;
        for(var line=0;line<lines.length;line++) {
            rowCount += Math.ceil(lines[line].length/82);
        }
        versionElement.rows=rowCount;
    }
```

The problem is, i am not able to add it for all the textarea elements. I am just bale to get only one textarea elements.

I tried Windo.onload still i am getting textarea element count as 1. JS snippet is placed at the very bottom of the page as well.

the parent file which calls up the textarea is :

```
<div class="box-content">
<div id="pnl_{$id}">
{foreach from=$version item=version name=version}
        {assign var=textBoxes value=$version->textBoxes}
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit.TitlePane>
     {include file="addTextArea.tpl"}
    </div>
{/foreach}
</div>
</div>
```

The generated HTML looks like:

```
<div class="box-content">
<div id="productPanel_80920">
<div data-dojo-type="dijit.TitlePane" data-dojo-props="title:'Version 4 <span class=versionDate>2014-01-16 15:35:21</span>'">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="tableCell">
                    <textarea readonly class="readTextBox versionText" style="resize: none; outline: none; word-wrap: break-word;" spellcheck="true">   random text
                    </textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>        
</div>
<br class="box-divider"/>
<div data-dojo-type="dijit.TitlePane" data-dojo-props="href:'addTextArea.html?id=4059&version=3', title:'Version 3 <span class=versionDate>2014-01-10 14:52:46</span>',open:false"></div>
<br class="box-divider"/>
<div data-dojo-type="dijit.TitlePane" data-dojo-props="href:'addTextArea.html?id=4059&version=2', title:'Version 2 <span class=versionDate>2014-01-10 14:48:09</span>',open:false"></div>
<br class="box-divider"/>
<div data-dojo-type="dijit.TitlePane" data-dojo-props="href:'addTextArea.html?id=4059&version=1', title:'Version 1 <span class=versionDate>2014-01-10 14:47:41</span>',open:false"></div>
<br class="box-divider"/>
```

the textarea is populated anytime i click on the div.

Answer (score 1):

First off, the proper HTML would be this (you were missing a closing `>`):

```
<textarea readonly class="readTextBox versionText"></textarea>
```

Second off, `document.getElementsByClassName` returns a `nodeList` which is like an array.  You have to go through each DOM element in the `nodeList` to operate on all your textarea elements.

I'm not sure I know exactly what you're trying to do, but converting your code to perform the oepration you've code on each textarea returned, it would be something like this:

```
window.onload=function() {
    var items = document.getElementsByClassName("versionText");
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        var versionElement = items[i];
        var versionElementText = versionElement.value;

        var lines = versionElementText.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/);
        var rowCount = 0;
        for(var line=0;line<lines.length;line++) {
            rowCount += Math.ceil(lines[line].length/82);
        }
        versionElement.rows=rowCount;
    }
}
```

Comment: i am always getting items.length as 1 that is my problem.

Comment: @CodeMonkey - did you fix your HTML as my answer shows?  If so, then show us your actual HTML for more than one text area then.  Because if items.length is always 1, then you don't have multiple items with the `"versionText"` class name.

Comment: I do have, atleast that's what i have checked on the UI side. I have 18 such elements.  actual HTML is just coupled with a foreach loop. And yes textarea had that missing angle bracket, i just missed yo add it.

Comment: @CodeMonkey - Not much else we can do without seeing your actual HTML.  If `getElementsByClassName("versionText")` only returns one item, then there's only one item in your page with that class name at the time you run that code.  Are some of your items being added dynamically (perhaps after your code runs)?

Comment: @CodeMonkey - we need to see the generated HTML (what the browser sees) from View/Source in the browser, not what your template is.

Answer (score 0):

```
var objs=document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
for (var i=0;i<objs.length;i++){
  var obj=objs[i];
  if (!obj.className||obj.className!='versionText') continue;

  //do your transformation here
}
```

Comment: If the className is not exactly "versionText" you can check the substring by using indexOf.

Comment: How does this help solve anything?  The OP was using `getElementsByClassName()` which was already retrieving only the items with the right class name.

Comment: Guess I misread the question. Thanks for pointing it out. +1 for a good solution.

Comment: u can always go for tagName, but that would mess up a lot of things. Thanks anyways.